# Exception : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

i'm working on a project that is based on web scraping with .NET Framework and Html-Agility-Pack tool.

At first, i made a method that parse the Category list from https://www.gearbest.com and it's totally working fine.

But now i need to parse the products from each category list item.
For example there is appliances category https://www.gearbest.com/appliances-c_12245/, but when i run the method it returns an error : 
'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive'

Here is my code :

```
    public void Get_All_Categories()
    {
        var html = @"https://www.gearbest.com/";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

        var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/div/ul[2]/li[1]/ul/li//a/span/../@href");

        foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
        {
            Category c = new Category();
            c.Name = n.InnerText;
            c.CategoryLink = n.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
            categories.Add(c);
        }
    }
```

This is working pretty much fine.

```
    public void Get_Product()
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        var html = @"https://www.gearbest.com/appliances-c_12245/";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

        var x = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"siteWrap\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/p[1]/a");
        Console.WriteLine(x.InnerText);
        Console.WriteLine("done");

    }
```

But this method doesn't work and it returns that error.
How can i fix this please ?
P.S : I already saw some solutions about HTTPS handling but it didn't work for me, maybe because i don't understand it.
I would appreciate any help, thank you in advance.